# How to mock locations for UI Tests in Swift with KIF?

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, xcode-ui-testing, kif, kif-framework

I'm writing UI tests with KIF and I want to test clicking on a GPS button and autofilling with text. My issue is that I don't know how to get a faked location.

Preferably, I would like to do this **without changing my actual (non-testing) code.** Is there a way I can do this without having my real code call an extension behind a protocol for the CLLocationManager?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: No, I wasn't able to find a solution that worked in my app equally across simulator and devices.